Couldn't make migration from Entity Framework Core / ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC project
I can't do migrations in EF Core.
I try
enable-migrations -contexttypename Bulky.DataAccess.ApplicationDBContext 

and I get:

The type 'ApplicationDBContext' does not inherit from DbContext. The DbMigrationsConfiguration.ContextType property must be set to a type that inherits from DbContext

Here is the DbContext file:
using Bulky.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Bulky.DataAccess
{
    public class ApplicationDBContext: DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDBContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasData(
                new Category() { Id=1, Name="Action", DisplayOrder = 1},
                new Category() { Id = 2, Name = "SciFi", DisplayOrder = 2 },
                new Category() { Id = 3, Name = "History", DisplayOrder = 3 }
                );
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasData(
                new Product
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Title = "Fortune of Time",
                    Author = "Billy Spark",
                    Description = "Praesent ",
                    ISBN = "SWD9999001",
                    ListPrice = 99,
                    Price = 90,
                    Price50 = 85,
                    Price100 = 80
                });
            //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}

And here is project file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.7">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.7">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="8.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Bulky.Models\Bulky.Models.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Bulky.Utility\Bulky.Utility.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I tried:
enable-migrations -contexttypename Bulky.DataAccess.ApplicationDBContext

and I get:

The type 'ApplicationDBContext' does not inherit from DbContext. The DbMigrationsConfiguration.ContextType property must be set to a type that inherits from DbContext

I tried to find the answer without any result

enable-migrations from EF6, EF Core uses different tooling.


Couldn't make migration from Entity Framework Core / ASP.NET Core 8.0
MVC project

According to your shared error and description it has couple of reason throwing above exception.
First of all, you are using EntityFramework-6.5.1 and EntityFrameworkCore-8.0.7 together which is of course incorrect. So when you use enable-migrations is meant for Entity Framework 6 (EF6) rather than Entity Framework Core (EF Core). Since your project uses Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 8.0.7, you should be using EF Core migration commands instead of EF6 ones.
Therefore, you could remove this reference:<PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.5.1" />
Correct Steps:
Considering your scenario, you should use following migration command.
If you are using visual studio nuget package manager console, you could use:
Add-Migration NameOfYourMigration
But if you are using CLI command, in that scenario you could use:
dotnet ef migrations add NameOfYourMigration
I am using visual studio nuget package manager console, in order to test your scenario and its working as expected:


Apart from that, you might encounter one additional issue while executing migration. That is foregign key conflict, becuase within your OnModelCreating product definition you haven't pass any foreign key which is CategoryId. So you could fix that issue. You should do as following:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasData(
        new Category() { Id = 1, Name = "Action", DisplayOrder = 1 },
        new Category() { Id = 2, Name = "SciFi", DisplayOrder = 2 },
        new Category() { Id = 3, Name = "History", DisplayOrder = 3 }
        );
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasData(
        new Product
        {
            Id = 1,
            Title = "Fortune of Time",
            Author = "Billy Spark",
            Description = "Praesent ",
            ISBN = "SWD9999001",
            ListPrice = 99,
            Price = 90,
            Price50 = 85,
            Price100 = 80,
            CategoryId = 1 // This key you should include
        });
    //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

Output:



Note: Please refer to this official document for additional assistance.

Thanks for your comment. It really helped.
I've get idea about confusion between EF and EFCore
instead of
Add-Migration addProductFK
I've run
EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration addProductFK
and it helped

Thanks for your response, I am glad to know it helped you.

In case you want to know how to accept answer, you could check it.
